# React material-ui deafultValue async problem with firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, material-ui

I'm setting up a settings page for a logged-in user. He should be able to see in the field the pre-existing value loaded from firestore and edit it.

Problem: the value is not displayed in the field because, I think, is not "available" yet when the material-ui field load.

The page isn't showing me any error. It just doesn't work.

This is the call to the firestore database, and it works fine. Checked with console.log:

```
const [show, setShow] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const data = await db
      .collection("shows")
      .where('uid', '==', currentUser.uid)
      .get()
      setShow(data.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

This is the TextField code:

```
<TextField
              variant="outlined"
               required
               fullWidth
               id="showName"
               label="Show Name"
               name="showName"
               autoComplete="showname"
               defaultValue={show.lenght && show[0].showName}
             />
```

It loads fine, but it's empty. So it doesn't load the defaultValue from the firestore database.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the prop "defaultValue". DefaultValue can't be updated after the first render because it's for components that are not controlled as the doc said https://material-ui.com/api/input/#props.

So you have to use "value" prop.
I create this simply example (try to change "value" prop with "defaultValue"): https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-playground-forked-f8np5?file=/app.jsx

Comment: Thank you Luca. It now displays correctly but the user can't edit it.

Comment: I think you have to add the onChange method
`onChange={(e) => { setShow(e.target.value); }}`